# Royden's non degenerate interval

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm working on Real Analysis problems, and I'm stuck on the following:

Show that a non degenerate interval of real numbers fails to be finite.

Royden's book has a theorem from the section where this question comes from saying "A non degenerate interval of real numbers is uncountable", but we aren't allowed to use this.

All I know is that a non degenerate interval of real numbers contains more than one member. I thought about just working with the case of at least $x_1,x_2\in \mathbb{R}$, but I'm not sure what to say after:

Let $E=\{a,b\in \mathbb{R}| x_0=a<x_1<x_2<b=x_n\}$. Recursively, we can define $x_{i+j/2}$=$x_i+\frac{x_i-x_j}{2}$ for $j<i$. This produces a midpoint for every subinterval, thus we can find an infinite set inside of E. Thus not countable?

Can anyone give me a hint or an overall idea? Not looking for complete solutions, please.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you allowed to use the fact that $\mathbb{Q}$ is dense in $\mathbb{R}$? The midpoint approach should also work for showing that the interval is infinite.

Comment: I believe so. It was featured in the previous section.

Comment: You could show that being an interval $I$ is equivalent to $x, y \in I$ and $x < z < y \Rightarrow z \in I$.